# where is c++filt source code?

Tags: c++

Does anyone known the link of c++filt source code. I want call c++filt in my code as a library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Linux you can use `/usr/include/demangle.h` which comes with `binutils-dev` package. You'll have to link to the `libiberty` from `binutils`.

Answer (score 6):

it's part of binutils:

http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/

Answer (score 4):

Given different compilers can mangle differently, each tends to ship with a custom c++filt.  But, most systems will already have a demangling library function available somewhere.  On my Linux box I found /usr/include/c++/version/cxxabi.h header defining __cxa_demangle() (see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html).  I thought I'd used some other function in the past though, but can't find the details (EDIT: probably the demangle version İsmail documents).  On AIX there's a demangle.h.

EDIT: on most systems with pstack and c++filt programs (i.e. Linux and Solaris), the following should work...

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

struct X
{
    void f()
    {
        std::ostringstream cmd;
        cmd << "pstack " << getpid() << " | c++filt";
        if (FILE* f = popen(cmd.str().c_str(), "r"))
        {
            char buffer[1024];
            int n;
            while ((n = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, f)) > 0)
                std::cout.write(buffer, n);
        }
        else
            std::cerr << "popen() failed\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    X x;
    x.f();
}
```

...output...

```
#0  0x003539be in __read_nocancel () from /lib/tls/i686/libc.so.6
#1  0x002ff590 in _IO_file_read_internal () from /lib/tls/i686/libc.so.6
#2  0x002fe522 in _IO_new_file_underflow () from /lib/tls/i686/libc.so.6
#3  0x00300371 in __underflow () from /lib/tls/i686/libc.so.6
#4  0x0030079d in _IO_default_xsgetn_internal () from /lib/tls/i686/libc.so.6
#5  0x00300733 in _IO_sgetn_internal () from /lib/tls/i686/libc.so.6
#6  0x002f666c in fread () from /lib/tls/i686/libc.so.6
#7  0x08048c36 in X::f ()
#8  0x08048ac0 in main ()
```

Notice that __read_nocancel etc are NOT C++-mangled identifiers: they're just internal C function names, using the reserved-for-implementation leading-underscore-and-uppercase-letter or leading-double-underscore convensions.

`X::f()` *was* a mangled identifier and *has* been demangled.

Comment: how about solaris, the printstack just doesn't demangle. should I print stack to a pipe, and read , demangle the msg?

Comment: @dma: Sample code above - tested under Linux but should work on Solaris.  Cheers.

Comment: I like the libstdc++ link.  But I can't in good conscience give a +1 to something that advocates using `popen()` like this. :P

Comment: @asveikau: I wasn't actually advocating it - simply illustrating how to do what @dma asked about in his comment above. That said, would I advocate it? I'm indifferent. This kind of stack printing thing is typically done as a near-final step in the deliberately fatal handling of a failed assertion or catastrophic error: there's no particular need to internalise the code: if the extra memory overhead of popen()/sh etc stops it working, so be it; if it's slower, who cares - it's once in a blue moon stuff. And `pstack | c++filt` is more portable and less heavily wedded to any given OS.

Comment: how about AIX, mt__trce can't used in c++?

Comment: @dma: I'm not sure.. sounds good, but I haven't got an AIX box handy to test on.  It may or may not demangle....

Comment: @Tony: thank you so much, the demangle.h works good in AIX; but I wanna know wether c++ abi was supported by aix?

Comment: @dma: Every C++ compiler must embrace some ABI standards, but they may use different ones on different OS.  There's no single industry-wide "C++ ABI", not even a single standard for name mangling.  That's why you often need to use the c++filt or library function shipped by the same compiler that compiled the code.  I'm not an expert on this stuff though: for more details, you could put it to the wider SO community in a new question.  Cheers.

Comment: I just would like to add that your comments also provide great info and could be on the answer itself :)