# How to "decrypt" linker method names?

Tags: c++, debugging, backtrace

I'm using backtrace to print application's stack trace and I'm getting something like

```
libQtCore.so.4(_ZN11QMetaObject8activateEP7QObjectPKS_iPPv+0x843) [0x7f889d20cf33]
libQtGui.so.4(_ZN7QAction9triggeredEb+0x32) [0x7f889d76c2f2]
libQtGui.so.4(_ZN7QAction8activateENS_11ActionEventE+0xb0) [0x7f889d76d670]
libQtGui.so.4(+0x6242f4) [0x7f889db862f4]
```

Is there any way to convert "linker-names" to "source-names" and get code line numbers from offsets?

I want to have backtrace, looking like this:

```
libQtCore.so.4 (QMetaObject::activate(QObject):1022)
libQtGui.so.4  (QAction::triggered()::47)
```

UPD.

I understand, this technique may work or not work or work bad because of compiler specifics. I want to "demangle" linker symbols at least in gcc and visual c++.

Comment: @fjardon , can I use this method from source code? Is there any

    char * s = cpp_filt(MyStackString);

Comment: @fjardon, c++filt will only work with gcc names, while MSVS or any other compiler may use different rules.

Comment: @Arenim, c++filt is a command line tool for Linux. It is not a function.

Comment: Yes, i see. It works for me, but I'm sure, it uses some library, capable for usage in application, right?

Comment: @Arenim: I'd look into source code if you need it that badly :).

Comment: "it uses some library, capable for usage in application" I think what you want is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4779945/1422630

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Under gcc you can use [**c++filt**](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.16/binutils/c_002b_002bfilt.html) to decipher the mangling.
- Under Visual studio you can [**undname**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x49w699.aspx)

Once you have the function name you at least on Windows you can use **[DIA SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eee38t3h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)** to get the source file line numbers etc

Answer (score 2):

This is called [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). Read the article on Wikipedia please, since citing it here would be too much for an answer.